# Rstudio Shiny dateInput: Limit on destinct day

Tags: r, date, shiny

As the title already said. I want to limit the drop down calendar on a specific day, e.g. every Tuesday or each second Wednesday.

This is a standard example of the input element:

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
              dateInput("date", "date:", value = format(Sys.Date(),"%Y-%m-%d"))),
         server=function(input, output) {})
```

Using parameters for `min=` or `max=` one can limit the selection, e.g. on the day before and after today.

```
shinyApp(ui = fluidPage(
              dateInput('date', "date:", value=format(Sys.Date(),"%Y-%m-%d"),
                        min=format(Sys.Date()-1,"%Y-%m-%d"),
                        max=format(Sys.Date()+1,"%Y-%m-%d"))),
          server=function(input, output) {})
```

But how to limit the selection on a specific date, such as every or second tuesday or on the first Monday each Month? Is this somehow possible?

Comment: There's already a ticket to add this feature https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/174

Comment: @PorkChop Thanks for the info. Then I have to wait until this feature is implemented.